# Hide Attribute in product view page if value of attribute = "abc"

Tags: attributes, view

visit [link](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/chhota-bheem-chutki-wall-decor-magnetic-cutout-15cm.html) , search for word " abc" using CTRL + F,

you can see attributes : "Brand" & " charactar"

[image: enter link description here]

we gave attribute values as "**abc**" for lot of attributes.

we want to **hide the attribute in product view page** if the **value ="abc"**

we are using following code displaying attributes in product view page :

app/design/frontend/default/em0113/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_product = $this->getProduct()
?>
<?php if($_additional = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>

    <div class="fp1"><?php $Pro_name =$_product->getName();?>
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Specifications Of '."$Pro_name") ?></h2><br/><br/>


    <table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
        <col width="25%" />
        <col />
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>

        <?php $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
       if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && (trim((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)) != '')) { ?>
        <?php if ($_data['code'] == 'gendernew'): ?>

        <tr><th colspan="3"><?php echo $this->__('') ?></th></tr>
        <th class = "tablehead" colspan="3" > GENERAL </th>
        <?php elseif ($_data['code'] == 'productweight'): ?>



        <tr><th class = "tablehead" id="prod_dim" colspan="3"><p style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0% ! important; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 100%; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px ! important;" class="Product_dim">Product Dimension</p><?php echo $this->__('PRODUCT DIMENSION') ?></th></tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
            <tr>
                <th class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table')</script>
<?php endif;?>

<?php

$attribute_value = 'xyz ';
if (strlen($attribute_value) > 0)
{
   // code to display the value
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just validate it in the first line after foreach:

```
...
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
    <?php $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']); 
    if($_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) == 'abc') {
        continue;
    }
    ?>
...
```

Comment: i added like this : http://pastebin.com/7ZXxwSGn

please check link

Comment: there is a syntax problem, please check it with an IDE: `... ->getValue($_product) == 'abc') ...`

Comment: please check link and updated code : http://pastebin.com/k4ZFV9uc

Comment: for what? just try it..

Comment: i updated your code, getting this error again : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in app/design/frontend/default/em0113/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml on line 72

Comment: Can you go to the line 72 and see what's happen? my code part doesn't add any unclosed `{}` so that unnecessary `}` comes from your own code. please make a little effort too. the error is pretty self-explained.